# ZK - redirect the user back to previous page

Tags: java, redirect, navigation, zk

Any ideas on how to redirect a user back to the previous page cleanly and robustly?

I'm only concerned about redirecting them back if the previous page was within the app itself. I've thought about storing some kind of DIY history in the user's Session but that doesn't seem clean or robust. I'm aware we can redirect the user with `Executions.sendRedirect(url)` but I'm not sure of the best way to get the previous page's URL.

ZK has it's own [Browser History Management](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Patterns/Browser_History_Management) but I don't think that's of use when trying to initiate a *real* browser redirect.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
// check if request needs to be sent back
if (!isValidRequest()) {

  // get the current execution context
  Execution exec = Executions.getCurrent();

  // retrieve HTTP request, response objects
  HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) exec.getNativeRequest();
  HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) exec.getNativeResponse();

  // get the referring URL from HTTP header
  String referrer = request.getHeader("Referer");

  /* don't need to use this unless doing a forward (server-side)

  if (referrer != null) {
    URL ref = new URL(referrer);
    referrer = ref.getPath().substring(request.getContextPath().length());
  } else {
    referrer = "/index.jsp"; // home page
  }
  */

  // HTTP 301 redirect (client-side); encoding ensures URL rewriting if required
  response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(referrer));

  exec.setVoided(true); // no need to create UI; about to redirect
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what's happening here? Thanks.